# Prefill friend ids in fb:multi-friend-selector

Tags: facebook, iframe, fbml

I am displaying the use a [multi-friend-selector element](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector), and it works. But I'd like to be able to preselect some friends when the dialog opens, and I don't know if the API allows that. At least, is not listed on the documentation.

My code

```
  <fb:request-form 
   action='{{iframe_url}}/reqs' 
   method='POST' 
   content='Sending a request'> 
  <input type='hidden' fb_protected='true' name='friend_id' value='{{facebook_id}}'/> 
      <input type='hidden' fb_protected='true' name='req' value='{{req_type}}'
      <fb:multi-friend-selector 
       actiontext='Select the friends you want to send this request' 
       rows='3' 
       showborder='true' 
       email_invite='false' 
       exclude_ids='{{excluded_friends}}'>
     </fb:multi-friend-selector> 
  </fb:request-form>"
```

I've tried using the tag `prefill_ids`, but it doesn't seems to make any effect.

PD: Also, it appears to ignore the the `email_invite` option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that it is not possible right now. Only workaround is to use attribute `exclude_ids` in element [`fb:multi-friend-selector`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector/) and leave only friends that you want the user to choose from by excluding all the other friends.